# query taking long to execute

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using my sql, I want to delete repeating rows from table emaillikebusiness_2  which compares data from another table called per2 the query I am using is

```
delete 
FROM 
     emaillikebusiness_2 
WHERE 
    emaillikebusiness_2.Email_id
  IN (
    SELECT 
    per2.BusinessEmail2
    FROM 
       per2 );
```

the explain statement gives output

```
'1', 'PRIMARY', 'emaillikebusiness_2', 'ALL', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '30670', 'Using where'
'2', 'DEPENDENT SUBQUERY', 'per2', 'ALL', 'idx_email2person2', NULL, NULL, NULL, '24710', 'Range checked for each record (index map: 0x1)'
```

I have also created INDEX on both table and also tried creating index on individual table but still query is taking long time to execute. is there anyway i can reduce query execution time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL tends to optimize `WHERE ... IN (SELECT ...)` poorly. Use a JOIN instead:

```
DELETE e.*
FROM emaillikebusiness_2 AS e
JOIN per2 AS p
ON e.Email_id = p.BusinessEmail2
```

I've found that with `IN`, it will often do a full scan of the first table, searching for `Email_id` in the index of the second table, even if the first table is much larger than the second one. But with a JOIN, it does a more efficient match between the indexes of the two tables.

Answer (score 1):

Try this Out:

```
DELETE emaillikebusiness_2.* FROM emaillikebusiness_2
 INNER JOIN per2 ON emaillikebusiness_2.Email_id = per2.BusinessEmail2

Because in most cases, Inner Join is significantly faster than IN clause.
```

Comment: btw what is your type of table engine MYISAM or INNODB ?

Comment: thanks vivek for your kind effort but my query was already answered by another commenter... I am using InnoDB